# jquery is not working in greasemonkey 0.9.15 using @require

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

Today I was trying to write a user script in greasemonkey 0.9.15
When I create a new user script with the following, it works fine

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           test
// @namespace      http://poomalairaj.com
// @include        https://myserver.com/logon.aspx*
// ==/UserScript==


alert('hello world');
```

But after adding the @require to include jquery the script stops working

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           test
// @require        http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js
// @namespace      http://poomalairaj.com
// @include        https://myserver.com/logon.aspx*
// ==/UserScript==


alert('hello world');
```

Now even if I remove the @require, still the script is not working for the page.
I have to remove the user script altogether and create a new one to test again.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks
Poomalairaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your Firefox version?

Anyway, Greasemonkey's `@require` doesn't always work as it should.  **See [bug 1504](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1504).**

When creating a script through the `New User Script...` menu command, if you then add a `@require` directive it doesn't stick.

This issue will supposedly be **fixed when Greasemonkey 0.9.16 is released**.  In the meantime, use this workaround:

1. Create a new GM script in your text editor, not with the `New User Script...` menu command.
   ~~ **OR** ~~
   Save the created file outside of the `gm_scripts` folder.
2. Add `@Require` directives as desired.
3. Now, install the GM script by opening it with Firefox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>), or by dragging the file onto any Firefox window.
4. The script should now work, including the `@require`s.  If it does not, uninstall ("Remove") the old GM script (and any conflicting ones with the same name) and reinstall it as in step 3.